# column vectors to matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, k-means

I have a set of vectors `V_1, V_2, ..., V_n` that I would like to convert to a matrix. Each vector becomes a column vector in the matrix. The size of each vector is the same. Is there a simple function to do this? In the matrix section of `The R Book` it does not appear that this function exists.

What I am currently doing is:

```
mat=matrix(c(V1, V2, ..., VN), nrow=length(V1))
```

1. Is there some kind of matrix append function to append columns onto the end of a matrix?

**EDIT:** The end goal is to perform a `k-means` clustering with this matrix. The names of my vectors are not actually `V_1, V_2, ..., V_n`. The names of the vectors are substrings corresponding to the file name which the data come from (this is a 1-1 map). Eventually, I will be iterating over all files in a specific directory, extracting the data into a vector and then appending each column vector to a matrix.

Comment: Is there a rhyme or reason to how your vectors are named, are they literally V1 ... VN?  The other solution here would be cbind, but you are still going to have to name each and every one of your vectors.

Comment: My vectors are not named $V_1,\ldots,V_n$ however, there is somewhat of a rhyme or reason to the names of my vectors as they will be a substring of the filename that the data comes from.

Comment: FYI, your data structure and desired structure are pretty simple and easy to describe without requiring statistical understanding.  So, your question might be better asked on stackoverflow.  For now you don't have to do anything.  If enough other community members agree with my assessment it will be migrated.

Comment: I rather prefer your original approach to some of the more complicated methods.  But one small thing you can do differently:  instead of nrow=length(V1), you can use ncol=N, where N is the number of vectors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A command that can work for you is: 
`sapply(ls(pattern="V[[:digit:]]"),get)`
Where the argument in pattern is a regular expression that matches the vectors you want (and only the vectors you want).  Alternatively, given that the vectors are named from a substring of some file names, I assume you can create a character vector with each vector name as an element.  If so, you can replace the ls command with that vector.

**Edit**:  Matrix append by column would be cbind (column bind).  For example:

```
V1 <- rnorm(20)
V2 <- rnorm(20)
V3 <- rnorm(20)
mat <- matrix(c(V1,V2),nrow=length(V1))
(mat.app <- cbind(mat,V3))
```

Comment: `(mat.app <- cbind(mat, V3))` works when I run it on one vector, but when I apply it generally in a loop mat does not change. Any ideas?

Comment: Well... what is changing is mat.app not mat.  So in your loop you need to make sure that you are storing the new mat in the same name that you later will use as an argument in cbind.  E.g. mat <- cbind(mat,VectorToAdd)

Comment: You can do `do.call("cbind", lapply(ls(pattern="V[[:digit:]]"), get))` to automate the last step of `cbind`-ing the vectors.